# How to INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: php, sql

I've already checked here on stackoverflow and searched on google, but couldn't find my answer. I've created a rating system Thumbs up and down, only members could vote on a article. When a member votes, sql is updating the row voteup/votedown. Now I've made a new table called `vote` I've got there 5 columns `id, user, uID, ctitle, cID`

So If a member who is logged in as for ex: `Admin` and he thumbs up the article for ex: `I like coding` SQL `INSERT INTO` the table which is called `vote` `Admin` to `user` the title into `ctitle` but at the same time he needs to update the table called `post` the row `vote_up or vote_down`

I'm only receiving the error: Failed to vote,

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = new User();
$username = $user->data()->username;
function getAllVotes(mysqli $db, $id)
{
    $votes = array();
    if($q_13 = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = $id");

    if($r_26 = $db->query($q_13));
    if($r_26->num_rows==1) 
    {
        $stem = $r_26->fetch_object();
        $votes[0] = $stem->votes_up;
        $votes[1] = $stem->votes_down;
    }
    return $votes;
}

function getEffectiveVotes(mysqli $db, $id)
{
    $votes = getAllVotes($db, $id);
    $effectiveVote = $votes[0] - $votes[1];
    return $effectiveVote;
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

//current votes
$cur_votes = getAllVotes($db, $id);

//update votes


if($action=='vote_up') 
{
    $votes_up = $cur_votes[0]+1;
    $q_13 = "UPDATE post SET votes_up = $votes_up WHERE id = $id";
    $q_13 = "INSERT INTO vote WHERE user = '$username', cID = '$id'";
}
elseif($action=='vote_down')
{
    $votes_down = $cur_votes[1]+1;
    $q_13 = "UPDATE post SET votes_down = $votes_down WHERE id = $id";
    $q_13 = "INSERT INTO vote WHERE user = '$username', cID = '$id'";
}

    $r_26 = $db->query($q_13);
    if($r_26)
    {
        $effectiveVote = getEffectiveVotes($db, $id);
        echo $effectiveVote." Archers";
    }
    elseif(!$r_26)
    {
        echo "Failed to vote!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: different variables, different `query()` call

Comment: Your `INSERT` statements are wrong syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html. `WHERE` is for `SELECT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, not `INSERT`. Try `INSERT INTO vote (user, cID) VALUES ('$username', '$id')`. Also, you are overwriting your `UPDATE` -> `$q_13 = "UPDATE...` with your `INSERT` -> `$q_13 = "INSERT...`. Either change the variable name, or execute the query between each.

Comment: @Sean I've tried this `if($action=='vote_up') 
{
 $votes_up = $cur_votes[0]+1;
 $q_13 = "UPDATE post SET votes_up = $votes_up WHERE id = $id";
 $q_14 = $db->query("INSERT INTO vote (user, cID,) VALUES ('$username', '$ID')");
}` but he doesn't want to insert nothing into vote

Comment: What is the table structure for `vote`? Are your columns actually `user`/`cID`? Are any of the columns unique, causing a duplicate error? Also, your original code has `$id` (lowercase), but in your comment you have `'$ID'` (uppercase) and `$id`!=`$ID`

Comment: @Sean ` user, uID, ctitle, cID` and `id` is `AI` What I'm doing wrong I've tried `$q_13 . = INSERT INTO` This is new for me doing multi query's

Comment: A multi query will only work if you are using [`mysqli_muli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) and your first query would have to end in a semicolon `;`. Did you make the changes to both sets of queries, in the `if` and `else if`?

Comment: @Sean fixed ` $r_26 = $db->query($q_13);
 $r_28 = $db->query($q_14);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51064/discussion-between-user3490572-and-sean)